# Drawing rectangles with React Canvas multiple rectangles issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, canvas, html5-canvas

Hi i am trying to create draw app in reactJs typescript
i use hook for handle drawing in canvas

but i got issue that when i draw a rectangle it draw as multiple rectangles along the line i want it to be just one
Why won't my multiple rectangles draw in the canvas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPz8g.jpg)

the hook

```
export const useDraw = (
  onDraw: ({ ctx, currentPoint, prevPoint }: Draw) => void
) => {
  const [mouseDown, setMouseDown] = useState(false);

  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const prevPoint = useRef<null | Point>(null);

  const onMouseDown = () => setMouseDown(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (e: MouseEvent) => {
      if (!mouseDown) return;
      const currentPoint = computePointInCanvas(e);
      const ctx = canvasRef.current?.getContext("2d");
      if (!ctx || !currentPoint) return;

      onDraw({ ctx, currentPoint, prevPoint: prevPoint.current });
      prevPoint.current = currentPoint;
    };

    const computePointInCanvas = (e: MouseEvent) => {
      const canvas = canvasRef.current;
      if (!canvas) return;
      const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
      const y = e.clientY - rect.top;

      return { x, y };
    };

    const mouseUpHandler = () => {
      setMouseDown(false);
      prevPoint.current = null;
    };

    // Add event listenr
    canvasRef.current?.addEventListener("mousemove", handler);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpHandler);
    // Remove event listenr
    return () => {
      canvasRef.current?.removeEventListener("mousemove", handler);
      window.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpHandler);
    };
  }, [onDraw]);

  return { canvasRef, onMouseDown, containerRef };
};
```

draw function

```
  function drawRectangle({ prevPoint, currentPoint, ctx }: Draw) {
    const { x: currX, y: currY } = currentPoint;
    const color = chosenColor;
    let startPoint = prevPoint ?? currentPoint;

    ctx.beginPath();
    if (prevPoint) {
      ctx.rect(
        prevPoint?.x,
        prevPoint?.y,
        currX - prevPoint?.x,
        currY - prevPoint?.y
      );
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
```

Comment: You seem to be complicating it too much. Your flow should be:
1. on mouse down, set state of mouse pointer start location
2. on mouse up, set state of mouse pointer end location
3. draw rectangle with start and end locations

You could achieve this with a `useEffect` hook with a dependency on mouse up. Inside the `useEffect` you make the call to draw the rectangle with given start and end locations. I believe the behaviour you're seeing is because you've wrapped everything in the `useEffect` so your states are being wiped on re-render.